# Use of include in cmake?

Tags: cmake

I am confused as to what use does include serve in cmake.

Acc to official documentation

> Load and run CMake code from the file given. Variable reads and writes access the scope of the caller (dynamic scoping). If OPTIONAL is present, then no error is raised if the file does not exist. If RESULT_VARIABLE is given the variable will be set to the full filename which has been included or NOTFOUND if it failed.

So, how does this differ from find_package() ?

Comment: [version] argument, module, `<package>_FOUND will be set`, `a file called Find<package>.cmake` `CONFIG option`, `QUIET`... it just differs. Your question is unclear. `find_packet()` `Finds and loads settings from an external project` while `include()` `Load and run CMake code from the file given.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may treat a `find_package` as a convenient **wrapper** around `include` command which is specifically designed for **find packages**:

1. `find_package()` automatically **transforms name** of the package to the `Find<package>.cmake` file, which is included.
2. `find_package()` automatically **sets** some **variables** based on its parameters. E.g. `<package>_FIND_COMPONENTS` variable will contain list of requested components.
3. After the included file returns, `find_package()` may **check** the **variable** `<package>_FOUND` and emit a error if the variable is FALSE but the package is REQUIRED.

Actually, the points 1,3 are specific for MODULE mode of the `find_package`. In the CONFIG mode they are replaced with:

1'. The name of the included file is treated as `<package>Config.cmake` or `<package>-config.cmake` and the **search** is performed using completely **different algorithm** than in the MODULE mode (which like `include()` uses `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` variable).

3'. After the included file returns, `find_package()` may check the variable `<package>_FOUND` and **search for the next include file**, which can try to locate the package again. If no more include files are found and the package is REQUIRED, the error will be emitted.

More info about `find_package` work can be found in [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/find_package.html).